# MongoDB aggregate and count

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, mongodb-aggregation

A document in collection called 'myCollection' looks like this:

```
{ 
    _id : 57b4b4e028108d801738a472, 
    updatedAt : 2016-08-17T19:03:01.831+0000, 
    createdAt : 2016-08-17T19:02:56.887+0000, 
    from : 57b1c2fc4bf55ba009b36c84, 
    to : 57b1c75e4bf55ba009b36c85, 
}
```

I need to count the occurrences of 'from' and 'to' and end up with collection of documents like this:

```
{ 
    "_id" : 7b1c2fc4bf55ba009b36c84, 
    "occurredInFrom" : 12, 
    "occurredInTo" : 16
}
```

where _id comes from either '$from' or '$to'.

The incorrect aggregate query I've written is this:

```
{
  $group: {
     _id: "$from",
      occurredInFrom: { $sum: 1 },
      occurredInTo: { $sum: 1}
  }
}
```

I can definitely see that _id: "$from" is not sufficient. Can you please show me the correct way?

Note: The structure of 'myCollection' is not final, if you think there is a better structure, please suggest it.

Comment: Related to [Mongodb aggregate query, or too complex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35161734/mongodb-aggregate-query-or-too-complex) and [Mongo Group and sum with two fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35549200/mongo-group-and-sum-with-two-fields/35550524#35550524)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
db.myCollection.aggregate([
  { $project:
    { _id: 0,
      dir: [
        {id:"$from", from:{"$sum":1}, to:{"$sum":0}},
        {id:"$to", from:{"$sum":0}, to:{"$sum":1}}
      ]
    }
  },
  { $unwind : "$dir" },
  { $group:
    {
      _id: "$dir.id",
      occurredInFrom: { $sum: "$dir.from" },
      occurredInTo: { $sum: "$dir.to" }
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: exception: disallowed field type Array in object expression (at 'dir'),
code: 15992

Comment: It may be the my DB version, 3.0 mongolab sandbox. I will try to find a way to make it work in this older version. Thank you.

Comment: I can confirm your answer is correct for MongoDB 3.2, a version in which $project [supports array fields](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/3.2/#general-enhancements). If you can think of a 3.0 solution (without square brackets in $project) please share. Thanks.